# vim: how to redirect output from shell command ":!echo foo" to a buffer?

Tags: vim

Given two buffers side by side, with the source code in buffer 1, how do I to run the compiler (or any command line program) and see its output (`stdout`) in buffer 2?

Also, how do I use the current or specified buffer as `stdin` to this command line program?

Comment: Look at [quickrun plugin](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-quickrun)

Comment: What do you plan to do with the `stdout`? Do you know about `:help :make` and `:help quickfix`?

Comment: @romainl I didn't know quickfix plugin, that's probably what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:r! command` to execute shell command and read its output to current buffer.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [`:h :b`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Ab):

```
:[N]b[uffer][!] [+cmd] [N]              :b :bu :buf :buffer E86
                Edit buffer [N] from the buffer list.  If [N] is not given,
                the current buffer remains being edited.  See :buffer-! for
                [!].  This will also edit a buffer that is not in the buffer
                list, without setting the 'buflisted' flag.
                Also see +cmd.
```

And for [`+cmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%2Bcmd):

```
                                                        +cmd [+cmd]
The [+cmd] argument can be used to position the cursor in the newly opened
file, or execute any other command:
        +               Start at the last line.
        +{num}          Start at line {num}.
        +/{pat}         Start at first line containing {pat}.
        +{command}      Execute {command} after opening the new file.
                        {command} is any Ex command.
```

So:

```
:2b +r!date
```

Would open buffer 2, and read in the output of the `date` command.